# Mongodb | Connection Refused

Tags: mongodb

Estoy en linux, al ejecutar el comando "mongo" me manda el siguiente resultado

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-04-27T18:58:39.362-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Impidiendo el inicio de mongo, ¿a que se debe y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Esta es una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793856/7934027) del servidor ingles: 1. Remueve el archivo lock.
```sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock```
2. Repara mongodb. ```sudo mongod --repair``` 
3. Empieza mongodb. ```sudo start mongodb ``` o ```sudo service mongodb start```

4. Checa el estatus de mongo. ```sudo status mongodb``` o ```sudo service mongodb status```

5. Empieza Mongo. ```mongo```

Comment: @AlexGarcia Sin resultado alguno despues de los comandos, sigue teniendo el mismo error...

Comment: @Keengan_Mtz Ya has usado mongo anteriormente?

Comment: @AlexGarcia Si te refieres a experiencia usandolo si, sin embargo lo acabo de instalar de nuevo en la maquina en la que estoy trabajando, y me encontre con ese problema

Comment: Me refería a si lo recién lo habías instalado, que linux estas usando?

Comment: Si, recien lo instale como te comento, hasta ayer funcionaba bien, hoy no lo hace, Uso Linux Lite (Derivado de ubuntu)

Comment: Ayer al terminar de usar mongo, ejecutaste el comando ```sudo service mongod stop```?

Comment: Revisa en tus procesos si está corriendo mongod probablemente este abajo